# Java server Webservice choosing xml or json

Tags: java, xml, json, web-services

I have to develop some webservices for a Tomcat8-Java8 server.

Now I have to choose the better language/protocol. Can you suggest the json apporach instead of xml?

This services will be very fast, then I need the better solution for a fast answer.

Comment: You can go for JAXB for Json rather than XML media format. JSON is simple and easy for tranversing.

Comment: I would leave your performance concerns re. your transport representation until you *know* these are issues. Your actual server may consume most request/response time, or perhaps your network transport costs, or, or. Having said that, you may want to implement a solution such that your client can specify JSON *or* XML (via HTTP headers) and your server can respond appropriately

Comment: This article is interesting : http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.fr/2013/08/optimizing-java-serialization-java-vs.html